# Terminal keeps closing once script starts while loop

Tags: bash, xdotool

I tried the following script to test the terminal and while loop, after executing, the script echoed all the variables in the terminal without closing, as I expected..

```
while read cat;
do
echo $cat
done </home/sacredmonkey/lkq_search/Catagoies.txt
```

But once I execute my script, the terminal will not stay open once the while loop starts..

```
count='1'

clear 
echo "Please enter the zip code"
read zip

clear 
echo "Please enter the year"
read year

clear
echo "Enter the make of the car"
read make

clear
echo "Enter the model"
read model

while read cat;
do
count=$((count+1)) &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool mousemove 75 745 && 
sleep 1 && 
xdotool click 1 && 
xdotool mousemove 175 115 click 1 && 
sleep 1 && 
xdotool click 1 && 
sleep 1 &&
xdotool type "https://xxxxx.orderxxxxx.com/vehiclePartxxxxx.aspx?company=001&language=en-us" &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool mousemove 700 245 &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool click 1 &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool type $zip &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool mousemove 765 295 click 1 &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool type $year &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool mousemove 765 318 click 1 &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool type $make &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool mousemove 765 346 click 1 &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool type $model &&
sleep 3 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool mousemove 765 380 click 1 &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool click 1 &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool type $cat &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool mousemove 690 435 click 1 &&
sleep 5 &&
xdotool key ctrl+s &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 1 &&
xdotool key KP_Enter &&
sleep 2 &&
xdotool key ctrl+q &&
sleep 2 &&
cd /home/sacredmonkey/lkq_search/results
sleep 1 &&
mv 'Vehicle Part Lookup By ZipCode.html' 'Vehicle Part Lookup By ZipCode'$count'.html'
sleep 1 &&
done </home/sacredmonkey/lkq_search/Catagoies.txt
```

Comment: The last `&&` before `done` doesn't seem right. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: Any chance one of those mouse clicks is on the "X" button at the top of your window?